# PHP exec() ZIP command not working for specific directory

Tags: php, zip, compression, exec

I am creating an encrypting ZIP backup of my project. I am using `exec() command` to archive the files and folder with encryption in PHP but the issue is - the files and folder are archives from the root directory but I want a specific folder to archive.

I also try to change the directory multiples time but it same also starts from `home3` in cpanel.

below the code, I am using for archive -

```
$path = realpath('./../../'); //CORRECT DIR
$password = "test";
$zipFileName = "backup.zip";
exec ("zip -r -P {$password} {$zipFileName} {$path}");

OUTPUT Archive directory : home3\USERNAME\public_html\DOMAIN\FOLDER 
I want it to achieve only \FOLDER DIR
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be a simple fix by just adding `cd $path &&`  to the beginning of the `exec` command:

`exec("cd $path && zip -r -P {$password} {$zipFileName} {$path}");`

Edit:

Mind, that the generated zip file is now in the specified `$path` directory.
So you might also want to move the file to a specific folder by adding the wanted location in front of `{$zipFileName}`:

Edit 2:

I think `exec("cd $path && zip -r -P {$password} /wanted/location/{$zipFileName} *");` is what you want.

Comment: @Satyam Sorry, it was my fault. I've edited my answer.